# Spring data rest repository with exported = false hides other repo with exported = true

Tags: spring-data-rest

Does anyone know if it's possible to have two spring data repos for a single resource, but only one of them exported?

When I do this, neither repo is exported:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(exported = true)
public interface BookRepo extends JpaRepository<Application.Book, Long> { }

@RepositoryRestResource(exported = false)
public interface BookRepo2 extends CrudRepository<Application.Book, Long> { }
```

Comment: That should work if you annotate the former with `@Primary. That will turn `BookRepo` into the primary repository for `Book`.

Comment: if you post this as an answer then it will show up as answered on the listings, potentially being more helpful to others who will then know there's an answer

Comment: @OliverGierke, I tried what you suggested, but it didn't make any difference. :(

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you have two repositories on the same type - `Application.Book`
also one is `JpaRepository` and the other is `CrudRepository`.
`JpaRepository` extends from `CrudRepository`.

may be you could assess why you need 2 repositories on the same type.

instead you could just use one with `JpaRepository` and then
you can use `@RestResource(exported=false)` to hide specific methods rather than having to hide repository interfaces.